# How to Pass data to controller using post method of javascript in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want pass data from View to Controller along with one variable indicating what I need to perform on controller

Here is code for view
function addUpdateData(data)

```
{
    alert(data);
    $(function(){
      $.ajax({
        method : "POST",
        url: "welcome/addupdate",        
        data: {id: data},        
        success : function(response)
        {
          alert(response);
        }
      });
    });
}

<input type="submit" id="add" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addUpdateData(id)" value="Add"></button>
```

Below is code for routes.php

```
Route::post('welcome/addupdate','FormController@addUpdateData');
```

Below is code for controller

```
public function addUpdateData(Request $req)
    {
        $id = $req['data'];
        return $id;
}
```

I want to receive posted data on controller with data variable where I will get whether I will add or update data..

I am getting error of Method Not Allowed
I don't know what I am Missing!!!

please help

Answer (score 0):

You're almost home. You made a mistake in your controller. It should looks like:

```
public function addUpdateData($id, Request $req)
    {
        $input = $req->all();
        return $id;
}
```

Your routing:

```
Route::post('welcome/addupdate/{id}','FormController@addUpdateData');
```

It's because you dosen't pass data with key `data` but straight like the js object is defined. It's better to use $.post method like this:

```
$(function(){
  $.post("welcome/addupdate/" . data, $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
});
```

I think is more clear.

Comment: Hello, Filip Koblanski thank you for your response.. This isn't working for me.. on controller I want values from HTML elements as well as value of data from which I came to know about whether I have to do update or add operation.. please help to get HTML data along with value of variable 'data'

Comment: OK. I've updated my answer. I changed your routing and serialized form data that can be pass with the post request.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, maybe you forgot to give Post the @CSRF field for token. With @CSRF blade, Laravel will generate the token